# Change partition sizes after windows removal?

Tags: windows, partitioning

Let's say we install ubuntu side by side with a windows installation.
At that time, we will NOT have much space to play with so:

/ - 5gb
/swap - 1gb
/home - 5gb

After that, we decide to remove windows. And we have much more space to play with.

Question:
What program can we use, in order to easily change all partition sizes after windows removal?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can really recommend [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), at their homepage you can download a live-cd or live-usb image that can do it all in a nice easy to use gui tool. You have to boot from some live disk since you cant resize a partition that is already mounted.

There is some generel documentation/guide to gparted [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/generalities/gparted.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you think you're going to end up in this situation, I'd recommend installing from an Alternate CD to start with so that you can use LVM.  LVM will let you add & resize logical volumes later, even while running (except for / which can only be resized from a live cd).

If you're already installed and in this situation, boot from a live cd and use GParted, which I think is included on the live cd.

Answer (score 0):

QTParted should do the trick for you.

http://qtparted.sourceforge.net/